# First row from each group based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Id Date
1 5/11/2015
1 5/11/2015
1 5/12/2015
1 5/13/2015
2 5/11/2015
2 5/11/2015
2 5/12/2015
2 5/13/2015
3 5/14/2015
3 5/15/2015
3 5/16/2015
3 5/17/2015
4 5/13/2015
4 5/13/2015
4 5/14/2015
4 5/15/2015


ID Name
1 Roy
2 Jame
3 Jani
4 Romi
```

I am not able to get the first row matching with second table

I want to get only one row from each table group by ID where date is greater than today's date (i.e. 5/11/2015), like as shown below.

```
Id Name Date
1 Roy 5/12/2015
2 Jane 5/12/2015
3 Jani 5/14/2015
4 Romi 5/13/2015
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cross apply` or `correlated subquery` to do this

```
select * from Table2 t2
cross apply 
(select top 1 [date] from table1 t1
where t2.id = t1.id
AND t1.[date] > convert(date,getdate())
ORDER BY [date] ASC) CS
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bc3c/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table with `GROUP BY` to get each id's lowest date (after today). Then `JOIN` with t2:

```
select t1.id, t2.name, t1.date
from (select Id, min(Date)
      from table1
      where Date > getdate()
      group by id) t1 (id, date) join table 2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Read the question one more time

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `row_number()`:

```
with cte as (
    select t2.id, t2.name, t1.date, 
           row_number() over (partition by t2.id order by t1.date) rn
    from table1 t1
        join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
    where t1.date > getdate())
select id, name, date
from cte
where rn = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/201eb/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CTE` + `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.[Date],
       t2.Name,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.[Date] ASC)
   FROM dbo.Table1 t1
   INNER JOIN  dbo.Table2 t2
     ON t1.ID = t2.ID
   WHERE t1.[Date] > GetDate()
)
SELECT ID, Name, Date
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8850b/3/0)</kbd>

The `ORDER BY t1.[Date] ASC` specifies which row you want to keep, in this case the row with the oldest date, use `DESC` if you want to keep the newest.